# Vue multi-type prop validation

Tags: vue.js

How to validate multi-type props in Vue? I have the following code and passing the `icon` attribute as a boolean won't pass validation.

```
icon: {
  type: [String, Boolean],
  default: null,
  validator: value => ['start', 'end'].includes(value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `typeof` keyword to determine the type of the argument then decide to pass or not.

```
icon: {
  type: [String, Boolean],
  default: null,
  validator: value => typeof value === 'string' 
                ? ['start', 'end'].includes(value) 
                : value // it will pass if value is true else not.
}
```